# RC circuit oscillator

Tags: clock, converter, current-limiting

I want to make a simple RC oscillator circuit that produces waveforms of  [image: this type:]

How can I do so?

Comment: Please give an example of the RC oscillator you might have considered when making that choice.

Comment: Without actual values for frequency and duty cycle, this isn't really an answerable question. Why do you ask specifically about an RC oscillator, as apposed to other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- Use 555 to generate very low on-time. I'm not sure whether it'll be practical as you may end up with ridiculously low component values.
- Generate a clock with 555 or relaxation oscillator *(doesn't have to have 50% duty-cycle but better to keep on- and off-times long enough)*. And run it through a CR high-pass filter. Thanks to its differentiating behaviour the output will be rising and  falling edges of the input clock (with short decaying due to the presence of R). So it won't give you perfectly short edges. But you can play with values to find a sweet spot. The cut-off frequency of the filter should be, of course, higher than the input's frequency. But should be low enough to chop off the pulses.

[image]

<sup>Img Source: [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_3.html) et.ws article</sup>

With a diode placed across the R the negative pulses can be chopped off (clamped to Vf of the diode, so it's better to use a schottky for minimum voltage drop). Also, it's better to pick the C first and calculate R accordingly. Note that as you decrease R the pulses will get shorter but the amplitude will drop as well.

Here's a quick example for 100 kHz (blue: input, green: output):

[image]